# java types in org.bson.BSONObject

Tags: java, xml, mongodb, bson

I'm currently learning the [BSON java library for mongodb](http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/) and I'm trying to transform a **org.bson.BSONObject** into XML in order to transform it with a **XSLT** stylesheet.

What kind of java types can I find as values in a BSONObject from a Mongodb ? Of course there will be:

- BSONObject (internal doc)
- java.lang.String
- ???

what are the others ? BigDecimal and BigInteger ? boolean, int, long, double ? Timestamp.. etc... ??

thanks,

Pierre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had to search for it too, but according to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-dev/msg/568081e174f07b35?pli=1) mongodb-dev post mapping is done like this:

```
 NULL            null
 UNDEFINED       null
 BOOLEAN         Boolean
 NUMBER          Double
 NUMBER_INT      Integer
 NUMBER_LONG     Long
 SYMBOL          String
 STRING          String
 OID             mongodb ObjectID
 REF             DBPointer
 DATE            Date
 REGEX           Pattern
 BINARY          DBBinary
 CODE            (exception)
 ARRAY           DBList
 OBJECT          DBObject or DBRef
 TIMESTAMP       DBTimestamp
 MINKEY          String: "MinKey"
 MAXKEY          String: "MaxKey"
```

[This](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Types) article on mongodb.org is a good resource for it, too.

*Edit:* Had a look at the source: org.bson.types.* is having a number of classes for BSON types. org.bson.BSONDecoder is decoding a BSON string and does the mapping listed above.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way to operate on BSON would be to use [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org); although by default it operates on JSON, there are extensions to use it both on [BSON](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) and [XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-xml-databind). Since Jackson does data binding, you can bind BSON data into Java POJOs (with `bson4jackson`) and write out as XML (with `jackson-xml-databind`).
Transformation would be as simple as:

```
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValue(bsonMapper.readValue(bsonData, MyPojo.class));
```

if you have, or can create, `MyPojo` that maps all properties; or if not by specifying `Map.class` as the intermediate type to bind to.