# How can I check if a class belongs to Java JDK

Tags: reflection, java

I use an external library which return some `List<?>`.
I need to check if each object of this list is an Object of the JDK (String, int, Integer...).
Is this a proper solution?

```
List<?> list = externalLibrary.search(...);
for(clazz : list) {
    if (clazz.getPackage().getName().startsWith("java.lang"))
      // do something different
}
```

Is there a better one?

Comment: what is the clazz here?? the list that is returned??

Comment: Note that there are also packages starting with `javax`, `sun`, `com.sun` or maybe even `oracle` or `com.oracle` now.

Comment: Btw, what do you need that for?

Comment: a NoSQL database driver returns a `List<?>` for a query results. In case of simple type (int, String...), it returns a `List<String>`. But, in case of a complex type, it uses a special Object that needs processing before being returned to the user.

Comment: Why then don't you just check whether you get that special oject or a string? I also doubt you'll get more than the primitives, their wrappers, `String`, `Date`, `BigInt`, `BigDecimal` etc. returned (you'll most certainly get only the "data type" classes from the database, no inner core classes, no collections, no swing classes etc.). Thus you'll most probably have a set of at most 20 classes/types to check against.

Comment: this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725386/java-types-in-org-bson-bsonobject) seems to go in your way. thanks.

Comment: do testing 6-10 Java type with `clazz.equals(String.class)` is way better than testing `clazz.getPackage().getName().startsWith("java.lang")`?

Comment: Yves, it's not just testing for "java.lang". As we already stated you'd have to check more standard packages. Also, where do you get those numbers (6-10) from? With your loop it would just be the one check whether you have `String` or not. Another question: do you get a list of _classes_ or a list of _objects_? Your loop states `clazz` but your comments seem to indicate you get objects.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your definition of "object of the JDK" -- which could get quite fuzzy around the edges -- no, this isn't going to do it. The `java.lang` package is only a tiny part of all the classes included in the JDK.

You might check whether each object was loaded by the same `ClassLoader` that loaded `java.lang.String` -- i.e.,

```
if (theObject.getClass().getClassLoader() == "".getClass().getClassLoader()) ...
```

In general, a different `ClassLoader` will be used for system classes vs. application classes.

Comment: It is smart but IMHO not enough. In systems with single class loader all classes are loaded by the same class loader.

Comment: Don't you have a single class loader for all objects in the simplest configuration? Thus if you don't get another class loader this would not help to distinguish between the standard and third party classes.

Comment: @Thomas -- depends what "simplest configuration" we're talking about, I guess. This works for a command-line app running under Oracle's JVM, and would of course work in any web app. For Android, maybe not -- we're not *really* talking about a JVM there, anymore.

Comment: @yvesamsellem -- If you showed us your tests, maybe we could come up with something that would work for you (or tell you what's wrong with the tests.)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the definition, but I mean the simplest class loader configuration which would be just the system class loader, nothing more. But even if you have more class loaders, you couldn't tell that the system class loader would only load standard classes, could you? In JBoss, for example, you have a hierarchy and in certain configurations you could tell which classes are loaded with your application but if you go up the class loader hierarchy you'd eventually find other shared classes loaded by the system class loader (not only the standard ones).

Answer (score 2):

It is probably OK, just you have to check the following packages:

```
java
javax
com.sun
sun
```

probably others...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like class loader base answer. But it will return true also on StringBuilder. If you want to more narrow definition that is only "built-in" types, you can try to evaluate whether this is primitive type (such as int) or wrapper type (such as Integer) or String. You can write something like this:

```
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.TreeMap;



    public class Utils {

        private static Map<String, Class<?>> SUBST_MAP = new TreeMap<String, Class<?>>();
        private static Map<String, Class<?>> SIMPLE_MAP = new TreeMap<String, Class<?>>();


        static {
            SUBST_MAP.put(Byte.class.getName(), Byte.TYPE);
            SUBST_MAP.put(Short.class.getName(), Short.TYPE);
            SUBST_MAP.put(Integer.class.getName(), Integer.TYPE);
            SUBST_MAP.put(Long.class.getName(), Long.TYPE);
            SUBST_MAP.put(Float.class.getName(), Float.TYPE);
            SUBST_MAP.put(Double.class.getName(), Double.TYPE);
            SUBST_MAP.put(Boolean.class.getName(), Boolean.TYPE);
            SUBST_MAP.put(Character.class.getName(), Character.TYPE);
            SIMPLE_MAP.put(String.class.getName(), Boolean.TRUE);

        }




    /**
     * Gets the the class type of the types of the argument.
     * 
     * if substPrimitiveWrapper is true,
     * then if there is argument, that represent primitive type wrapper (such as Integer),
     *      then it will be substituted to primitive type (such as int).
     * else no substitution will be done.
     *
     * @param arg object.
     * @param substPrimitiveWrapper - wheteher to do primitive type substitution.
     * @retrun class type.
     */

    public static Class<?> getClassType(Object arg, boolean substPrimitiveWrapper){
        Class<?> classType = null;
        String className = null;
        Class<?> substClass = null;

        if(arg != null ){
            //making default classType
            classType = arg.getClass();
            if(substPrimitiveWrapper){
                className = classType.getName();
                substClass = (Class<?>)SUBST_MAP.get(className);
                if(substClass != null){
                    classType = substClass;
                }

            }
        }
        return classType;
    }

    /**
     * This method consider JDK type any primitive type, wrapper class or String.
     * 
     * 
     * @param arg object
     * @return where arg is JDK type or now.
     */
    public static boolean isJDKClass(Object arg){
        Class<?> classType = getClassType(arg, true);
        boolean isJDKClass = false;
        if(classType!=null){
            //if(String.class.equals(classType)){
            //  isJDKClass = true; //this is String, note that String is final
            //}
            assert classType!=null;
            String className = classType.getName();
            Boolean isFound = (Boolean)SIMPLE_MAP.get(className);
            if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(isFound)){
                isJDKClass = true; //this is predefined class
            }


            boolean isPrimitiveType = classType.isPrimitive();
            if(isPrimitiveType){
                isJDKClass = true; //this is primitive type or wrapper class
            }
        }

        return isJDKClass;
     }

    }
```

You can also optionally add support for such classes like `java.math.BigDecimal`, `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp`. Note, however, that they are not final, so I assumed that if somebody extended them even in the *trivial* way, it will not be considered as JDK class.

Answer (score 1):

We use the below class to check if the classes belongs to JDK

```java
public class JDKClass {

    private static Set<String> CS = new HashSet<String>();

    static {
        try {
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"),
                    "lib/classlist");
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String l;
            while (true) {
                l = r.readLine();
                if (l == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    CS.add(l.replace('/', '.'));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static boolean contains(String o) {
        return CS.contains(o) || o.startsWith("java") || o.startsWith("com.sun")
                || o.startsWith("sun") || o.startsWith("oracle")
                || o.startsWith("org.xml") || o.startsWith("com.oracle");
    }

    private JDKClass() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ClassLoader.getSystemResources` and then check from what jar is the class loaded (f.g. if it comes from rt.jar).

You will get URL's such as:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
```

Example code taken from SLF4j:

```
  private static String STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH = 
     "org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class";
  private static void singleImplementationSanityCheck() {
    try {
      ClassLoader loggerFactoryClassLoader = LoggerFactory.class
          .getClassLoader();
      Enumeration paths;
      if (loggerFactoryClassLoader == null) {
        paths = ClassLoader.getSystemResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
      } else {
        paths = loggerFactoryClassLoader
            .getResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
      }
  List implementationList = new ArrayList();
  while (paths.hasMoreElements()) {
    URL path = (URL) paths.nextElement();
    implementationList.add(path);
  }
    ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier solution is to thing of the problem this way:
write a method to identify all classes that are defined by you. In most cases, all user defined classes follow a pattern like com.something.something. Then if they do not belong to com.something.something, it is a JDK class